# Creating a radius of influence around points

Tags: qgis, vector

I have a vector file of points. What I need to do is create a circle with a radius of 12km round each point.
Would it be possible to then find out what percentage of my total map is covered with circles and what area is uncovered?

Comment: Do you know the area of your "total map". If so then divide the sum of areas of all the 12km circles by the total area. Or maybe I'm missing something in your question?

Answer (score 7):

Start by buffering your points;

Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Buffer

and set the buffer distance to 12000m.

This will give you the extended circles;

[image]

Then create a polygon equal to the area you wish to query (your total map) and then

Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Difference

and select your buffer layer and your total map layer. This should produce a polygon of the total area, minus the buffered regions

[image]

You can then go into the attribute table for your original total map layer and use the field calculator to create a new column, using the expression $area which will contain the area of your total map polygon.

[image]

If you then use the same process to calculate the area for your difference layer, you can work out its percentage coverage.